# Couldn't load admin interface due the error below

Tags: python, django

I've got following code and got two issues.
1. I couldn't get joins added up and not showing up on the page.
2. Admin interface is not loading.

I've re-created the DB checked the code thoroughly and really need help.

Views.py.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from.models import Join
from .forms import EmailForm, JoinForm

 def get_ip(request):
    try:
        x_forwarded = request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
        if x_forwarded:
            ip = x_forwarded.split(",")[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
    except:
        ip = ""
    return ip

import uuid
def get_ref_id():
    ref_id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:11].replace('-', '').lower()

    try:
        id_exists = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
        get_ref_id()
    except:
        return ref_id
def home(request):
    try:
        join_id = request.session['join_id_ref']
        obj = Join.objects.get(id=join_id)

    except:
        obj = None

    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        new_join_old, created = Join.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            new_join_old.ref_id = get_ref_id()
            if not obj == None:
                new_join_old.friend = obj
            new_join_old.ip_address = get_ip(request)
            new_join_old.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s" %(new_join_old.ref_id))

    context = {"form": form}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def share(request, ref_id):
    #try:
        join_obj = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
        friends_referred = Join.objects.filter(friend=join_obj)
        count = join_obj.referral.all().count()
        ref_url = settings.SHARE_URL + str(join_obj.ref_id)
        context = {"ref_id": join_obj.ref_id, "count": count, "ref_url": ref_url}
        template = "share.html"
        return render(request, template, context)
    #except:
        #raise Http404
```

Error message I am getting after commenting out exception is:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin
Join matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'ref_id': u'admin'}
```

Urls.py includes following.

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'joins.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<ref_id>.*)$', 'joins.views.share', name='share'),
)
```

Comment: firstly, you need to correct the intendation of ``def share`` correctly.

Comment: secondly, ``join_obj = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)`` this is NOT error message

Comment: please show the urls.py. and make sure the object is really in db that you are requesting.

Comment: Object does exists in DB.

Comment: What do you mean, you've shifted the admin URL? What does the code you're actually running look like? With the URLs as you've posted, you wouldn't get that error. But with the "share" view at the top, you would: the order matters.

Comment: I never had share view at the top. I just moved admin url in urls.py above when this error was showing up and moved it back to bottom when found the problem don't lie there. In regex docs it says sometime secondary regular expression may not pass it to admin url. So tried it just like that. Views are posted in edited question posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression in line

```
url(r'^(?P<ref_id>.*)$', 'joins.views.share', name='share'),
```

matches `admin/` as well you should use something less "greedy".